# ODE Explicit Approach

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For this function $h(x) = \exp(-2 (x-0.5)^2)$ I want to use explicit approach to solve the problem $dy/dx = -h(y)$ with $y(0)= 2$ in ODE.

What steps should I do exactly, I have no idea, all i have seen is two variable in function but I don't understand, very confused.

I have to solve ordinary equation with initial condition $y(0)$ in the interval $[0,1]$ with increment of $0.1$

Comment: Could you tell more on how the two-variable case looks and what was done to solve it "explicitly"? The exact solution requires the inverse of the $\rm erfi$ function (error function with imaginary argument), it is improbable that you were asked about that.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann the only info I have to use is these and solve dy/dx=−h(y)  with initial value

Comment: It sounds most likely that you have to find a numerical solution with some method that has the property of being explicit. Without more details there is nothing to do here. The formulation of your task has to refer to some previous lecture or section in a text book. Perhaps you can find clarifying details there.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann thanks for help, i have normally to solve ordinary equation with initial condition givin in the interval [0,1] with increment of 0.1

Comment: There are named methods like Euler (explicit, modified, improved), Heun (2nd and 3rd order), classical RK4 (Kutta's method), the likewise classical 3/8 method. Do any of these occur in or close to your task?

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann if you can help with euler mayb i would appreciate it, cuz I dont know how to do it

Comment: Just apply the method that you know how to do for $y'(x)=f(x,y(x))$ to $f(x,y)=-h(y)$. There is nothing deeper behind this.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann what do u mean, you mean doing this y' + h(y) = 0 ? and replace h(y) with its value ?

Comment: Can you check again your sources if the right side in the differential equation depends on $x$ or on $y$?

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann on y

Comment: Well then did you try to iterate $y_{n+1}=y_n-\Delta x\cdot h(y_n)$? Can you verify if that gives the correct results?